# Evaluate $\pi$ using While

Tags: series-expansion, homework

I am given the following exercise:

> Evaluate $\pi$ using the formula $\pi = 4 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{4}{2n +1}$ with precision $\epsilon = 0.0001$.

First I defined the function I need to solve:

```
Clear[f, x, x0]

f[x_] := 4 - Sum[(-1)^x*4 / (2*x + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

But I have no idea how to proceed.

EDIT: An example from my course notes is the following:

For the function $f(x) = e^{x-2} -2$ find the solution $f(x) =0$ with precision $0.01$.

Lines of inputs:

```
Clear[f,x,x0]
f[x_] := Exp[x-2] -2
fp[x_] := D[Exp[x-2] -2, x]
Plot[f[x], {x,0,4}]
exact = FindRoot[f[x], {x,4}]
x0 = 1;While[Abs[2.69315  -x0] > 0.01, x0 = N[x0 - f[x0] / fp[x0]]]; x0
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Part of the point of the question is for you to figure out, based on whatever you learned about series, how many terms to actually use in order to reach the desired accuracy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your formula should be either

```
4 + Sum[(-1)^x*4/(2*x + 1), {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

> Pi

or

```
Sum[(-1)^x*4/(2*x + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> Pi

The finite series approximation is then

```
Clear[f]

f[n_] := Sum[(-1)^x*4/(2*x + 1), {x, 0, n}]
```

As `n` increases, `f[n]` converges slowly to `Pi`.

```
With[{nmax = 150},
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 1, nmax},
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, Pi}, {nmax, Pi}}]}]]
```

[image]

```
Clear[n]

FindRoot[Abs[f[n] - Pi] == 0.0001, {n, 1000}]
```

> {n -> 9998.999974308344}

Although you can start the `While` at any nonnegative integer value for `n`  (e.g., `1`), I choose `9500` to speed up the convergence

```
n = 9500; While[Abs[f[n] - Pi] > 0.0001, n++]
```

The required `n` is then

```
n
```

> 9999

Comment: Great answer, thank you.

Comment: I would want to point out your `FindRoot` trick is much more lucky than it would seem. `f[n]` happens to expand into $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ function which converges towards zero, but doesn't have a real value at most real points (as it's a spiral on complex plane). `Abs` saves you sort of in an accident, especially because resulting function is luckily well-behaving. It is probably also luck in choosing the sum to try out that you even find a real-valued root...

Comment: @kirma - it makes no difference since the result of `FindRoot` is not required for the `While` which appears to be the desired approach.

Comment: @BobHanlon `While`-based approach is just fine. I was just pointing out that symbolic results that work in $\mathbb{Z}$ (`Sum`/`While`) don't necessarily behave similarly enough in `FindRoot`, which operates in $\mathbb{R}$/$\mathbb{C}$. This time we were lucky!